# Laravel Summernote doesn't want to save tag <src>

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, summernote

I have a problem here, I want to save a summary of the news that the user will create, I don't want if the user uploads an image, the  tag will not be stored in the summary column, how do I do that?

```
 $content = $request->content;
   $dom = new \DomDocument();
   $dom->loadHtml($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);    
   $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
   foreach($images as $k => $img){
      
       $data = $img->getAttribute('src');
       list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
       list($type, $data) = explode(',', $data);
       $data = base64_decode($data);
       $image_name= '/upload/'.time().$k.'.png';
       
       $path = public_path() . $image_name;
       file_put_contents($path, $data);
       $img->removeAttribute('src');
       $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
    }
   $description = $dom->saveHTML();
   $summernote = new News();
   $summernote->title = $request->title;
   $summernote->content = $description;
   $summernote->summary = I don't know what I'm going to write here
   $summernote->save();
```

Comment: you need to explain your question more you have just pasted your code, which package, its reference filenames, error, desired output , current output screenshot etc

Answer (score 0):

try  `@$dom->loadHtml($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);` this for `$dom->loadHtml($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`

Thanks